# Stored Procedure group by date set values for a missing date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In my stored procedure I return the total number of minutes grouped by the dates. The date ranges are one week from yesterday. The procedure is working fine. However, there's one issue I'm facing. Not always between the 7 days there will be any data for a particular day.

So for example, if I run my procedure today it returns this.

```
**Min  Date**
47  2014-08-03
153 2014-08-04
45  2014-08-05
166 2014-08-06
```

This particular person doesn't have any data for the 31st of July,1st and second of August. So there will be no data returned from stored procedure.

What I want to do is return 0 for the days where there're no records in the database.

```
**Min  Date**
0   2014-07-31
0   2014-08-01
0   2014-08-02
47  2014-08-03
153 2014-08-04
45  2014-08-05
166 2014-08-06
```

Here's the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAgentChartData]
(
@ABID BIGINT
)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

--RETURNING 7 DAYS WORTH OF DATA FROM YESTERDAY

DECLARE @TODAY AS DATE =GETDATE(),@WEEK AS DATE 

SET @WEEK =  DATEADD (DD, -8, @TODAY)

SELECT SUM(MINUTES) AS TOTALMINUTES, CONVERT(DATE, STARTDATE) AS DATE FROM PoLines 
    WHERE ADDRESSBOOKID = @ABID AND STARTDATE BETWEEN @WEEK  AND @TODAY
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, STARTDATE)


END
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT*

Added Hogan's suggestion. Still experiencing issue.

```
WITH Dates AS
(
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -7, GETDATE()) AS DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -6, GETDATE()) AS DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -5, GETDATE()) AS DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -4, GETDATE()) AS DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -3, GETDATE()) AS DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -2, GETDATE()) AS DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD (DD, -1, GETDATE()) AS DAY
)
SELECT SUM(MINUTES) AS TOTALMINUTES, CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day) AS DATE 
FROM Dates 
LEFT JOIN PoLines ON CONVERT(DATE, STARTDATE) = CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day) 
WHERE ADDRESSBOOKID = @ABID 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day)
```

Comment: You need to use a calendar table here. That way you pull your dates from the table and join to your business data. It is the only way you can get this to work. The challenge you are facing is that there are no rows so you have start with a table where the rows are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a small case like this I just make an inline table with a CTE.  Like this:

```
WITH Dates AS
(
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -8, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -7, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -6, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -5, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -4, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -3, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -2, GETDATE()) AS DAY
 UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD (DD, -1, GETDATE()) AS DAY
)
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(MINUTES,0)) AS TOTALMINUTES, CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day) AS DATE 
FROM Dates 
LEFT JOIN PoLines ON CONVERT(DATE, STARTDATE) = CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day) 
  AND ADDRESSBOOKID = @ABID 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day)
```

Because you are left joining from the Dates table you will get all elements of the Dates table and whatever elements of the PoLines table exist.  Then the group by will roll this up to 7 rows.

You can also setup a dates table in your DB to join from and use a where clause to limit the date range (this is a standard practice.)

Note, I don't have access to a DB right now so I did not test the SQL it might have a typo.

Comment: You don't really need a dates table either. You could use spt_values. e.g.  
WITH Dates AS
(SELECT DATEADD (DD, Number * -1, GETDATE()) AS DAY
FROM Master..spt_values 
where type = 'P' and number >0 and number < 9)

Comment: @ConradFrix - Yep that would work too. I guess I could replace "dates table" with "some table that has a sequential list with length greater than or equal to 7".  That seems like it might not be as clear.

Comment: Hogan, thank you for the reply. I tried the this example, but it's not returning any data.

Comment: StartDate is Datetime

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN PoLines ON CONVERT(DATE, STARTDATE) = CONVERT(DATE, Dates.Day)` if that works then change CTE to create DATE type not DATETIME

Comment: It returns data. But it's not showing 0 skipping dates.

Comment: Can't do that, since start date is used in the select statement but not in group. `is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @user1426542 - Change it there too. (see above)

Comment: It's returning data, but not the dates that missing. It actually returns data from the July 30th. :(

Comment: I have changed that. For the particular test I'm doing, I don't have any data for the 1st, second, and third of August. The output is not returning those days with 0. Updated my post with the latest code.

Comment: They are identical, except I removed the `-8` in select statement.

Comment: Attached a screenshot. Thank you for your help.